# Setting hardcoded value in bound attribute

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I have a component with a "label" attribute and since this label will not change, I want to specify it when I declare the component:

```
<parking-list
        label="PARKINGS"
        parkings="{{parkings}}"
        on-showparking="parkingList_showParkingHandler"></parking-list>
<parking-list
        label="SHOP AND GO"
        parkings="{{shopAndGoParkings}}"
        on-showparking="parkingList_showParkingHandler"></parking-list>
```

The label value is not rendered properly though. I worked around this with `label="{{'PARKINGS'}}"`. Is this simply not supported or will this be supported in a future release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should be fixed in 0.8.0 [see discussion](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!searchin/web-ui/bindproperty%7Csort%3adate/web-ui/Wt5lkIQVYFw/w7n1qDazcooJ)

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping this was a temporary workaround. Glad to see it fixed.